# How to define global variable across 2 files using Class

Tags: python, class, oop, global-variables, python-import

Here is the problem I am facing, I have a main script a.py that has defined a global variable, I have script b that has helper functions that need to use that global variable. I would like to directly use this variable instead of passing to function as parameter.
Below is the code:
**a.py**

```
from b import func1
class My_Globals:
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.global1 = "abc"
        self.global2 = "def"
        self.g = input
 
user_g = My_Globals("kkk")
func1()
```

This is
**b.py**

```
from a import user_g

def func1():

    print(user_g.g)
```

I come across to a circular import error, but I avoid importing *. I know there is an alternative that we can define global variable in c.py and import c in both files. But I would like to learn if there is any way we can implement global variable in Object class so it can be public for all scripts. Thanks in advance

Comment: If `a.py` imports `func1` and `func1` uses a global variable from `a.py` then why not define `func1` in `a.py` instead?

Comment: In "b.py" you can move the import into "func1".

Comment: @IainShelvington Hi, in my real case I have code for prediction, training, data generation, etc. The purpose is to sort different functions in different files.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I also noticed if we do this way, when we will run a.py, func1 will run twice

Comment: _Why_ do you want globals instead of passing parameters?

Comment: @LixiangWei If you run "a.py" it is once run as `__main__` script and when imported it is once again run as module `a`. To avoid the latter wrap "active" code like function calls in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard.